# Why are labels required for inputs with jquery.validate?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am just starting with jquery.validation and like it.  One reference I felt specifically helpful when trying to understand the big picture is http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Markup_recommendations.  One part I didn't understand is why labels need to be associated with each input.  Yes, I understand that labels are created to display error hints, however, these are different labels.  I couldn't detect any change on the label tag, and it works fine without it.  Anyone know why?  Thanks

> Each input has a label associated with it: The for-attribute of the label refers to the id-attribute of the input.

```
<label for="firstname">Firstname</label><input id="firstname" name="fname" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `label`is actually HTML element  that adds usability improvement for mouse users where if user clicks on the text within the  element, it toggles the control.

In HTML `label` is an optional element, That means you don't need to provide `label` for each `input`

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought/hoped but wasn't sure.